# Context not being passed through redux connect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux, react-redux

**Edit:** I was able to have the connected Child update on context change with the suggestion in the Redux troubleshooting of setting `{ pure: false }` however I needed to add this to all of the connected Components that are parents of the Child I want to be update. Seems odd and inefficient to have to do this to a lot of components.

---

First of all, I will describe what my desired end result is before diving into what I think the problem is.

I am wanting to access the params of [react router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) from within a grandchild component of my **Route component**. There are several references that say it is not necessary to sync the current route with the store if you are not using ["recording, persisting, and replaying user actions, using time travel"](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#react-router-redux) so I have avoided it so far. Dan Abramov states [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722584/how-to-sync-redux-state-and-url-hash-tag-params/36749963#36749963) that it is okay to keep them un-synced and to just use the route as the source of truth.

Similar questions that didn't have answers to my problems:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36633892/2300773
[Passing store through context with <Provider> not working in connect() based scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940405/)

Since **react-router** does not provide the current params as context, I have opted to add the current param as a context from the **Route component**. I can access the context all the way down the component tree until I reach a Child that has been setup using **connect()**. The initial rendering of the page gives the Child the correct context. However, when the context changes, the Child does not get updated. **connect()** appears to be stripping away the context link.

**Is this the desired behaviour of connect()? If so, how is a component supposed to access the route params without them being synced to the store?**

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/chadfawcett/btdhbpLx/1/) is a JSFiddle showing a very minimal scenario where context isn't updated past the "connected" component.

Here is a bit of my actual code where I am sending the current route param as context from the **Router component** (`/view/:viewSlug`). I **have** tried setting the component to `{ pure: false }` in **connect** as described in the [redux troubleshooting](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux) but had no luck.

### Parent (App) Component

```
class App extends Component {
  getChildContext() {
    const { viewSlug } = this.props

    return { viewSlug }
  }

  ...
}

App.PropTypes = {
  ...
}

App.childContextTypes = {
  viewSlug: PropTypes.string
}

...

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

### Grandchild (Day) Container

```
import Day from '../components/Day'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  ...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Day)
```

### Grandchild (Day) Component

```
class Day extends Component {
  ...
}

Day.PropTypes = {
  ...
}

Day.contextTypes = {
  viewSlug: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default Day
```

Comment: what version of React Router are you using?

Comment: @QoP I am using 2.4 (latest)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a quick discussion with Dan Abramov, there doesn't appear to be a *good* way to pass params down to various deep components. ([Discussion here](https://twitter.com/chadfawcett_10/status/729778772631654400)). Once React Router 3.0 is released, this will be very trivial to implement correctly.

## Workaround

Currently the only workaround I found was to set the Child Component, as well as any Ancestor Components between the Child Component and the Route Component, as an "un-pure" component.

This can be done with the options parameter when using the **connect()** function.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { pure: false })(MyComponent)
```

This information was found on the [Redux Troubleshooting page](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/dbbb9e578199388afa149b3677963d35bc1378c2/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem: I have a language param in a route path which I store as context and use in all components of my app. And when I connect redux store, context properties are not updating anymore.

As you mentioned, there is a `{ pure: false }` argument to force rerender the component more times than needed.

Another solution to not use context. You can use [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) to save and update changed URL in Redux store. It has its own action LOCATION_CHANGE which has a payload object:

```
routing: {
    locationBeforeTransitions: {
        pathname: 'view/someView',
        search: '',
        …
    }
}
```

For now it does not have params, but you can parse `pathname` and get them in old school regexp way. :)

And please read this issue, there are some other workarounds: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2517

**UPDATE:**

There is another way — save your app state in redux store:

```
…
import { setCurLang } from '../actions/langActions';

const App = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.actions.setCurLang(this.props.params.curLang);
    },
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps) {
        return nextProps.params.curLang !== this.props.params.curLang;
    },
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
        this.props.actions.setCurLang(nextProps.params.curLang);
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* here you can use your saved URL-param as prop,
                    and it will be updated each time react router changes */}
                {this.props.curLang}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        curLang: state.curLang
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators( { setCurLang }, dispatch)
    }
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

my reducer (this is simplified, of course you can use `combineReducers` here):

```
const curLang = 'de';

export default function reducer(state = curLang, action) {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'SET_CUR_LANG':
            return { ...state, cur: action.curLang }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and action:

```
export function setCurLang(curLang) {
    return {
        type: 'SET_CUR_LANG',
        curLang: curLang
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why We won’t receive `this.context` when we use react-redux [connect()](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connect)
is that we don't specify `contextTypes` check [this comment](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/193#issuecomment-158827093)

Add **`contextTypes`** like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Myapp.contextTypes = { store: PropTypes.object };
```

**Now**, we can find that `this.context` has a value and the **store** is available on `this.context.store`

For more illustration check [this comment also](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/193#issuecomment-159395029)